# Double integral with variable limits over implicit function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, implicit

I'm experiencing the problem because of variable limit and implicit funtion being together.

So let's simplify it to this:

> s(y)=y - our "implicit" function
>
> Int [Int(x*s(y)*dy, 1,x)*dx, 1, 2] - our double integral (which equals 9/8).

(So you can even separate in into 2 integral I_small= s(y)dy and I=I_small * x*dx)

All that I figured out:

1) I tried using quad2d (so there is no ploblem with variable limit) - but I can't put the root of implicit function in it . So it wotks for non-implicit function:

```
 function main
     quad2d(@myfun,1,2,1,@(x)x)
 end
 function value=myfun(x,y)
    value=x.*y;
 end
```

But for implicit I've tried that - and it doesn't work. I know there is something wrong with this code - matlab doesn't understand that argument "y" in function name and "y" in the function itself are the same. But don't know how to fix it.

```
function main
     quad2d(@myfun,1,2,1,@(x)x)
 end
 function value=myfun(x,y)
    f=@(s,y)s-y;
    value=x.*fzero(@(s)f(y,s), 0.5);
 end
```

2) This code solves the opposite I = s(x).*y and I can't understand how to switch x to y because fzero doesnt work if I place y in it instead of x(j)

```
function main
    quad(@myfun, 0,1)
end
function z=myfun(x)
    z=zeros(size(x));
    f=@(x,s) s-x;
    for j=1:length(x);
         s(j)=fzero(@(s)f(x(j),s), 0.5);
         h=@(y) (s(j).*y);
         z(j)=quad(h,1,x(j));
    end
end
```

3) I also tried the nested quads, but it only works with constant limits. Can't fiqure it out how instead of Upperlimit should I place @(x)x.

```
function main
    quad(@(y)y.*first_int(2),1,2)
end
function value=first_int(UpperLimit)
    value=quad(@(x)yfunction(x,1),1,UpperLimit);
end
function value=yfunction(x,l)
    syms y;
    f=@(x,y) l.*x-y;
    for k=1:length(x)
        value(k)=fzero(@(y)f(x(k),y), 0.5);
end
```

Could you guys help with that?

Comment: I'm not clear on what the function you're trying to solve actually is. And is there a reason you're not using `integral2`? You could also try symbolic math via `int`.

Comment: the real function s(y) is implicit and looks like const1/y^2=erf(s)+s/const2. To check the right answer I use simple s(y)=y. So I can't use int as it's symbolic - and you can't solve implicit function symboliclly . Yeah, thank you, I will be using integral2 - thought quad2d is the only one than numerically integrates double int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `quad2d` (as its modern and better counterpart `integral2`) requires that the function to be integrated accept matrices as inputs.

> The function Z=FUN(X,Y) must accept 2D matrices X and Y of the same  size and return a matrix Z of corresponding values.

On the other hand, `fzero` only solves one equation, not a whole bunch of them at once. So, in order for your implicit function to accept matrix inputs, it needs to be written with a loop:

```
function value = myfun(x,y)
    f=@(s,y)s-y;
    value = zeros(size(x));   
    for i=1:size(x,1)
        for j=1:size(x,2)
            value(i,j) = x(i,j)*fzero(@(s) f(y(i,j),s), 0.5);
        end
    end
 end
```

Then `quad2d(@myfun,1,2,1,@(x)x)` or `integral2(@myfun,1,2,1,@(x)x)` will work.

Comment: Thank you! Now it's clear for me. You saved me hours!